# Check if there exists in an Excel sheet a string of length within several strings in cell

Tags: string, excel, string-length

I would like to see if there exists a string of length 25 in a certain cell. The problem is that the cell I want to check, contains several strings seperated by a space. Of these strings, I want to know if there is a string of length 25.

If I use for example the LEN-function, I get the total length of the strings in the cell, while I want to see if there indeed exists a string of length 25 between all the strings in that cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to split the string into separate strings to use `Len` so use `Split` and loop through the array of strings. This is the code for a single cell check:

```
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim TestLen As Integer

' Get the cell and split it into separate strings in an array
WrdArray() = Split(Range("A1"))

' Loop the strings array to find any that equal 25 characters long
For i = LBound(WrdArray) To UBound(WrdArray)
    TestLen = Len(WrdArray(i))
    If (TestLen = 25) Then
        MsgBox "found one"
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: I used this code and it works indeed for a single check. How can I use this code to execute it on each row of a given range and print "found one" or "nothing found" in the cell next to the row in the range that has been checked?

Comment: I would encapsulate this into a function, passing through the cell to check as an argument. The function can return whether the length is matched or not. Then you can loop the cells you want to check calling this function for each cell. Use what is returned to output to the cell next to it, found or not.